# WPF UI control vendors - ActiPro, Telerik, Xceed, Infragistics, DevExpress and others

Tags: wpf, datagridview, treeview, wpf-controls, propertygrid

I have to choose a commercial WPF UI control library for our project.

Browsing the web I have found these major vendors:

- **Actipro**: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/WPFStudio/Default.aspx
- **Telerik**: http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx
- **Xceed**: http://xceed.com/pages/TopMenu/Products/ProductSearch.aspx?Lang=EN-CA&Category=0617b4dd-af9a-4e34-a1a1-d1129237d614
- **Infragistics**: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Overview
- **DevExpress**: http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/NET/OnlineDemos.xml

There may be others, of course.

My impression is that Actipro and Telerik give more controls than others. ActiPro, however, is the only one with WPF property grid control, which, as they claim knows to present the common properties of a multiple selection and allows to edit it. But, they lack the data grid and tree view controls, which Telerik has.

The UI we have in mind will surely need the following controls:
 - Property Grid
 - Tree View
 - Data grid
 - Wizards

Which means, that no single vendor can satisfy this list, because of the Property Grid control.

My question is this - did anyone need to embed these controls in his/her app and how did (s)he manage it?

BTW, by no means do we wish to implement any of the controls ourselves, so, please, do not propose it.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the question then? If you don't want to implement the controls, what use is any implementation experience to you?

Comment: Bad wording, granted. I have replaced the word implement to embed.

Comment: Hey mark! Please update with your own answer what was final solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid. It is free and it would fill the gap.

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Adding my answer for others reference -

I have evaluated `Telerik`, `Infragistics` and `Syncfusion` controls for my projects and have extensively used Telerik and Syncfusion.

From my experience I feel Telerik are best designed controls and best suited for MVVM. I have seen telerik's code as well and they use MVVM pattern very nicely to implement their controls and samples.

I haven't used Infragistics extensively so can't comment whether they suit for MVVM or not but they have good and stable controls.

Syncfusion is worst when it comes to WPF, there controls are not that great and will be tough to use with MVVM (i.e. taking benefit of WPF features like Binding, teplates etc.). They are neither well designed nor very stable.

Answer (score 0):

We have used Actipro.
My idea is when selecting components to use it is always choice, that cannot be evaluated until tried.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried 3 UI libraries for Silverlight (not WPF, as originally asked):

- Telerik
- Infragistics
- Component One

The final winner is Component One, which gave us the best experience leaving the other two far behind. We have still libraries of the first two lingering around, but they are not used anymore.

BTW, we have recently decided to migrate to HTML 5 on the client side and Java on the server side abandoning .NET and Silverlight altogether.

Hope my answer helps others to make the right choice.